# LED strip forgets last setting when turned off

Tags: electrical, led, dimmer-switch

In the staircase at my home an electrician installed a LED strip in the handle. I can dim the lights to desired intensity using a springloaded switch and a timer turns on the light in the morning and off at night.

The problem is that every time the light is turned on it's on **full blast** which is really annoying in the morning.

Can I solve this using the hardware I have without having to call in an electrician?

Driver: LED dimtrafo MDR 12V  [specs](http://www.hidealite.uk/Products/Indoor/Drivers/LED_Constant_Voltage/Dimmable_trafo/LED-dimtrafo_MDR/2783490-800838.html?variantId=2790980&searchText=Mdr)

Timer: Theben  TR610 top2 [specs](https://www.theben.de/en/tr-610-top2-g-6100110)

[Photo of timer, driver and switch overview](https://photos.app.goo.gl/6MpyFZdxqqJ25xSM6)

[image]

[Closeup photo of driver](https://photos.app.goo.gl/Di6e3ApCP7udyYw56)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE, David. Can you post your pictures in-line so that the question will still make sense when the links die? A make and model and link to the driver datasheet would also be of benefit. (At the moment anyone else with the same problem couldn't find your post because the make and model aren't mentioned in the text.)

Comment: I tried uploading the photos using SE's own hosting but an error was thrown. How can I inline the photos using Google photos as host?

Comment: You can't. The site uses Imgur. There was a problem last week. Try again later. The number of photos and links you can add is limited by reputation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The controller needs to be continuously powered in order to remember the dimmer setting. Unfortunately, the electrician wired the timer so that it interrupts power to the controller.

One way to fix this would be to purchase a relay that has a 230V coil and contacts rated to handle the DC current at the output of the controller.

Wire the controller's AC input directly to the mains.

Wire the output of the timer to the relay coil.

Wire the relay contacts in series with the output of the controller (i.e., between the controller and the LED strip).